# Voltage rating of 3.5mm jack audio output

Tags: voltage, audio, signal, proteus

I am building an audio amplifier using TDA2030.

I want to know what is voltage (RMS or peak-peak) rating of typical audio output from 3.5mm jack.

I am doing a simulation in Proteus, and I am having trouble deciding what should be the input voltage and frequency which should be provided to the amplifier through a sinr wave generator to get the best possible result (similar to the actual situation.)

If I provide a higher or lower voltage signal to amplifier I didn't get the required result and can damage my speaker afterward.

I want to design an amplifier so that it doesn't damage my 5W speaker.

Suggestions are welcome for the circuit below.

[image: My simulation]

[image: Signal generator prop.]

Comment: This all ***depends***. You need to look at the source. There isn't a universal answer which tells you all things about all sources, unfortunately. You can, if you like, provide a nice "volume control" which allows you to adjust the gain of your circuit. This is the usual way, I think, for something "commercial" to be used by ignorant users who don't know and don't care and just plug things in. That said, there are various "standards." But in this day, now, with cell phones and so many other electronic devices, it's become a no-man's land again. So you may want a way to manually adjust things.

Comment: You can also add [automatic gain control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automatic_gain_control), I suppose. But this has its own problems -- most notably that it compresses the dynamic range of what you run through it. And that's usually not a "good thing." So it's back to the manual volume control, my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I want to know where should the volume controller should be placed in the above circuit.

Comment: There are a few things I don't like about the circuit. But I'll hold myself in check on that. Regarding the volume control, for a TDA2030 IC I'd probably start with the idea of a potentiometer. Input to one end, ground to the other end, and the wiper take-off to the amplifier. That will get you just "so far" and it's not perfect. But it may be enough for you. If not, I'd modify that by first studying a variety of source devices and their voltage ranges (which for headphone outputs will vary quite widely and require some effort on your part.) From there, I could compose a variable gain pre-amp.

Comment: The TDA2030 and TDA2030A are old and are obsolete, not made anymore. With your 18V supply the maximum output at clipping is a little less than 5W so your little speaker will be fine. but if you turn up the volume too high you might get a severely distorted  output power of 8W which is bad for your speaker and bad for your hearing.

Comment: Thanks for your responses, now I have a few more doubts. Which IC is better to drive a 5W speaker TDA2030 or LA4440? For mono audio.

Comment: Can I supply 12V power to the above circuit through a wall adapter rated 12V 2Amp?

Comment: @Vishal Do you really need 5W? Can you live with 1W, for example? Where is the 5W coming from, exactly?

Comment: @Vishal do u know if ur speaker is 5W peak or 5W RMS ? Either way, it will not give stellar sound at it's limit of operation. I would expect best sound at 50 to 75% of it's power rating (so somewhere around 3W)